# Import native node modules correctly in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, native

I've been using node for quite a while now (for my backends) and typescript with ionic (for frontend). On Ionic i realize I have managed to avoid many pitfalls and errors just because of TypeScript. I have hence decided to convert all my backends that are in pure JS to TypeScript.

The first obstacle I've run into is how to import native node modules like `http`, `os` and `child_process`, among others, correctly.

On most modules you can usually do something like `import { some_export } from 'that_module'`. I can also see the type definitions for node in the **@types/** repo. I've tried `import { http, os } from 'node'` but I get a complaint that

> /node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts is not a module

My question hence is how should I import native node modules?

Answer (score 13):

I've managed to solve this issue thanks to some light reading from [this simple tutorial](http://brianflove.com/2016/11/08/typescript-2-express-node/)

To my understanding, the native modules are **standalone modules** that are not namespaced under ***node***. You should therefore import from them directly.

Simply done so:

```
import * as http from "http";
import * as os from "os";
import * as path from "path";
.
.
.
and so on
```

Comment: One more thing - you will need to tell the typescript compiler where do these come from - it is done in the tsconfig.json, with the following line:
 "compilerOptions": { "types": [ "node" ] }